# How to add objects to menu with getMenu().add

Tags: java, android

I want to populate a popupmenu with Objects so that when a user clicks on one of the items, I can verify what that item is and take the appropriate action.

The way I'm doing it now, it populates the list but only with the strings and I can't seem to refer to the objects they represent.

Here's the code (inside of onClick)

```
case R.id.buttonInventory:
                   final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, buttonInventory);
                   popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
                   //add items to drop down list
                   for(Weapon weapon: player.getWeapons()){
                       popup.getMenu().add(weapon.getName());
                   }
                   popup.getMenu().add("Testing");

                   popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                       public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                           if(item.getClass().equals(Weapon.class)) {
                               Toast.makeText(
                                       MainActivity.this,
                                       "You Clicked a weapon" + item.getTitle(),
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                               ).show();
                           }
                           else {
                               Toast.makeText(
                                       MainActivity.this,
                                       "You Clicked a non weapon",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                               ).show();
                           }
                           return true;
                       }
                   });
```

The problem is in the if statement.  The program doesn't recognize any of the menu items as Weapon objects and therefore skips over that one and shows the toast saying "You Clicked a non weapon".   How can I make it so that the items in the menu list represent the objects that their name came from?

Answer (score 0):

Hey what does getName() return. In your situation you can use

```
popup.getMenu().add(weapon.getClass().toString());
```

and for comparison

```
item.getTitle().equals(Weapon.class)
```

It depend on when you want to add item to popup menu you simply write

```
popupMenu.getMenu().add("Hello").setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: This didn't change anything.  It's still comparing a string to the weapon class. I need to know how to load objects into the menu list if that possible.

Comment: Did you check the updated answere.Did it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a `popup.getMenu().add(<String>)`, you are only adding a String to the items. So your comparison

```
if(item.getClass().equals(Weapon.class))
```

doesn't fit as the `item.getClass` will always return `MenuItem` because of which your above comparison will always fail.

To achieve this you can do the following:

```
int WEAPON_ID = 0;
```

Then in the init phase of popupMenu

```
final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, buttonInventory);

popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());

for(Weapon weapon: player.getWeapons()){
        popup.getMenu().add(WEAPON_ID,Menu.NONE,Menu.NONE,weapon.getName());
    }  //this adds the weapons to the WEAPON_ID group
```

While checking, you can check the groupID

```
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if(item.getGroupId() == WEAPON_ID) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            "You Clicked a weapon" + item.getTitle(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            MainActivity.this,
                            "You Clicked a non weapon",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

To go one step ahead, if you want to identify the object these were associated with, then you can specify the itemID attribute as

```
popup.getMenu().add(WEAPON_ID,weapon.getID(),Menu.NONE,weapon.getName());
```

and you can get the same in the MenuItem as `item.getItemId()`

Comment: please let me know if this fixed your issue. Happy to help.